# Create Dynamic json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a dynamic json string.
Json looks like:

```
{
"getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "x345dsfg",
        "transactionKey": "456tyYYUU7876"
    },
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
        "amount": "20.00",
        "profile": {
            "customerProfileId": "123456789"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The values in json like name, transactionKey, transactionType, amount, customerProfileId will vary for different users.

I am following this method to create json:

```
var getHostedPaymentPageRequest = new Object();            

    var merchantAuthentication = {};
    merchantAuthentication.name = "x345dsfg";
    merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = "456tyYYUU7876";
    var transactionRequest = {};
    transactionRequest.transactionType = "";
    transactionRequest.amount = "20.00";

    var profile = {};
    profile.customerProfileId = "123456789";

    transactionRequest.profile = profile;

    getHostedPaymentPageRequest.merchantAuthentication = merchantAuthentication;
    getHostedPaymentPageRequest.transactionRequest = transactionRequest;

    getHostedPaymentPageRequest = JSON.stringify(getHostedPaymentPageRequest);
```

But its not giving back the right values.

How do I make a valid json in the desired format?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include more detail about the problem? Which values are not right? What differences are there between your current result and the result you're aiming for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
var money=document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var customerprofileid = "1926616706";
    var merchantAuthentication = {};
    merchantAuthentication.name = "ser555";
    merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = "fgrtyujjj";
    
    var getHostedPaymentPageRequest = {
        "getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {
            "merchantAuthentication": {
                "name": merchantAuthentication.name,
                "transactionKey": merchantAuthentication.transactionKey
            },
            "transactionRequest": {
                "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                "amount": money,
                "profile": {
                    "customerProfileId": customerprofileid
                }
            },
            "hostedPaymentSettings": {
        "setting": [        { 
            "settingName": "hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl",
            "settingValue": "{\"url\": \"http://localhost:52965/IframeCommunicator.html\"}"
        }]
    }
        }
    };
  getHostedPaymentPageRequest = JSON.stringify(getHostedPaymentPageRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided code (if we add a `console.log` on `getHostedPaymentPageRequest`) displays the following result (which is how it should behave):

```
{
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "x345dsfg",
        "transactionKey": "456tyYYUU7876"
    },
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "",
        "amount": "20.00",
        "profile": {
            "customerProfileId": "123456789"
        }
    }
}
```

The only meaningful difference that I see between this and the expected result is that in your expected result the JSON starts with

```
{
    "getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {
         ...
    }
}
```

For that you have to wrap your `getHostedPaymentPageRequest` object in another object. So instead of doing this:

```
getHostedPaymentPageRequest = JSON.stringify(getHostedPaymentPageRequest);
```

add braces like this:

```
getHostedPaymentPageRequest = JSON.stringify({ getHostedPaymentPageRequest });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a reference..

I've split the object based on what it's doing and I've obtained two separate objects: `merchantAuthentication` and `transactionRequest`. For each object I created a separate function who return an individual object, because in the future you might want to add more fields therefore it will be easier to you to know were to place them :)

```js
function createMerchantAuthObject() {
  let merchantAuth = {};
  merchantAuth.name = "x345dsfg";
  merchantAuth.transactionKey = "456tyYYUU7876"

  return merchantAuth;
}

function createTransactionRequestObject() {
  let transactionRequest = {};
  transactionRequest.transactionType = "authCaptureTransaction"
  transactionRequest.amount = "20.00"
  transactionRequest.profile = {};
  transactionRequest.profile.customerProfileId = "123456789"

  return transactionRequest;
}

function getHostedPaymentPageRequest() {
  let request = {}
  request.getHostedPaymentPageRequest = {}
  request.getHostedPaymentPageRequest.merchantAuthentication = createMerchantAuthObject();
  request.getHostedPaymentPageRequest.transactionRequest = createTransactionRequestObject();

  return request; // used in order to print the whole object
}

const myObject = getHostedPaymentPageRequest();
console.log(myObject);
```